# get JSON file or info from AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have piece of good working code that downloads and parses JSON from server and returns result in `+JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` of `AFJSONRequestOperation`. success (and also  failure)part of method takes block as an argument with `id JSON` argument in it. If I understand right - this object is for representation of JSON file or it's content. I need to have a possibility to send this JSON file (or it's text representation in every other text format) to email, using MFMailComposeViewController. So, two questions:

- how can I get this JSON content from this file?
- do I need register .json filetype to have possibility to send it using MFMailComposeViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I get this JSON content from this file?

You can get the JSON data response (before it's converted to Foundation objects by NSJSONSerialization) from

- `operation.responseString` (as NSString), or
- `operation.responseData` (as NSData).

You'll want the latter if you're going to attach it to an e-mail.

> do I need register .json filetype to have possibility to send it using
>   MFMailComposeViewController?

You need to call [`[MFMailComposeViewController -addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMailComposeViewController/addAttachmentData%3amimeType%3afileName%3a).  You can get the mime-type from the `operation.response.allHeaderFields` NSDictionary. You can also use the official standard, `application/json`, or `text/json`, which is commonly used as well.

Comment: so simple... Thank you, Aaron! I wasn't enough inspective to detect this property

Answer (score 1):

The response in the succes if not JSON but the object representation of the JSON. Most likely a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

What you need to do is either use a normal HTTP request and send that string to the `MFMailComposeViewController` or change the `JSON` object back into a JSON string:

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSON options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = nil;
if (jsonData) {
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error creating JSON: %@", error);
}
```

Then you can pass the `jsonString` in your `MFMailComposeViewController`.